# UTF-8 encoding in Jmeter during http recording

Tags: character-encoding, jmeter

I am recording web requests in non english language by using Jmeter proxy recorder.

In some cases Jmeter shows the encoding correctly and I see that utf-8 is written in "content-encoding" field in the HTTP request.

The problem is that in some cases Jmeter doesn't show the encoding correctly and the field "content-encoding" is empty or has the value "us-ascii".

in both cases the source code of the recorded page has meta charset of utf-8.

How do I make Jmeter always use utf-8 during recording?

Thank in advance,

Gadi

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Request sampler documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

> **Content encoding**
>
> Content encoding to be used (for POST, PUT, PATCH and FILE). This is the character encoding to be used, and is not related to the Content-Encoding HTTP header.

So the blank value is normal given you are recording [HTTP GET requests](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.3).

If you want to override the Content encoding setting for all the HTTP Request samplers just add [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element to your test plan and specify `UTF-8` encoding there.